# How to pass array to java method from jni

Tags: java, android, arrays, callback, java-native-interface

I am trying to pass a `int array` from `JNI to Java`. When I pass `single or multiple` `int` value, `it works` but passing `array` is not working. Every time app crash and return the following error

## Error

```
Invalid indirect reference 0x48609264 in decodeIndirectRef
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d....
```

## JNI

```
jclass dataClass = env->FindClass("com/mypkg/project/DemoNative");
javaClassRef = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(dataClass);
javaMethodRef = env->GetMethodID(javaClassRef, "onDataReady", "([II)V");
jobject javaObjectRef = env->NewObject(javaClassRef, javaMethodRef);
jint array[2] = {1};
jintArray result;
result = env->NewIntArray(2);
env->SetIntArrayRegion(result,0,2,array);
env->CallVoidMethod(javaObjectRef, javaMethodRef,result,2);
```

## Java

```
public void onDataReady(int[] array,int len){
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you wanted to say.

Answer (score -1):

The line

```
jobject javaObjectRef = env->NewObject(javaClassRef, javaMethodRef);
```

is definitely wrong. It tries to use the method ID for **onDataReady()** as a constructor.

You probably need

```
jmethodID javaDefaultConstructor = env->GetMethodID(javaClassRef, "<init>", "()V");
jobject javaObjectRef = env->NewObject(javaClassRef, javaDefaultConstructor);
```

Note that jmethodID is not a reference: you can find the ID once and use it from any thread and on any instance you like. It's just a number, constant at least for the lifetime of your application.

Comment: onDataReady() is definatly not a contructor. Where is the method name in GetMethodID? Can you please explain this line?

Comment: `"<init>"` denotes constructor. You can use **javap** to find the exact enchantment that fits your class.

Comment: But onDataReady() is not a constructor. And I want to call a specific method not the constructor.

Comment: Also I can call a method without any problem which doesn't take array as a parameter.

Comment: Maybe the difference was that the method that the other method you tried was static?

Comment: … or maybe there is an error message about a JNI call being made while an exception is raised? JNI call to **NewObject** failed, but if its exception is not cleared, and the call to **NewIntArray** caused the crash. To be a loyal citizen, JNI expects you to call **ExceptionCheck** after each JNI call that may fail, e.g. **FindClass**.